# What is the benefit of developing opensource git-respository for the developer?

Tags: optimization, open-source

Developing an **OR** open-source Git repository empowers developers by providing a platform for

- collaboration
- fostering transparency
- engaging with a broader
  community
- building a positive reputation,

and contributing to continuous improvement in both individual skills and the software being developed.

Would you like to share your personal experience in this regard ?
What did you get out of it? financially or reputation ?

Comment: What kind of open source git repo do you mean? For a use case implementation? Or for a solver itself?

Answer (score 1):

Another obvious benefit is that users will try many configurations and ideas, find possible bugs, thus making the library more robust.